# Can't run app on android 13 with just_audio

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

i am using just_audio and dart:2.18.0 flutter 3.3.0 the error causing when targeting android Api 33

C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audio_service-0.18.4\android\src\main\java\com\ryanheise\audioservice\AudioService.java:312: warning: [deprecation] stopForeground(boolean) in Service has been deprecated
stopForeground(!config.androidResumeOnClick);
^
C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audio_service-0.18.4\android\src\main\java\com\ryanheise\audioservice\AudioService.java:586: warning: [deprecation] stopForeground(boolean) in Service has been deprecated
stopForeground(false);
^
C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audio_service-0.18.4\android\src\main\java\com\ryanheise\audioservice\AudioService.java:795: warning: [deprecation] get(String) in BaseBundle has been deprecated
final KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)mediaButtonEvent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audio_service-0.18.4\android\src\main\java\com\ryanheise\audioservice\AudioServicePlugin.java:1142: warning: [deprecation] get(String) in BaseBundle has been deprecated
Object value = bundle.get(key);

Comment: Did you add permission in AndroidMainfest

Comment: i solve my problem by running the command flutter_pub_upgrade

Comment: If you solved it, please write an answer and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved by running the following command

```
flutter pub upgrade
```